# Postgres - declare variable outside of a function

Tags: postgresql

Silly question, how do I sit in PGAdmin and declare a variable to be used later in inline statements?

Declare par_callcenterid integer;

yields:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 1: Declare par_callcenterid integer;

Answer (score 0):

Some people use temporary tables for storing such values. Another
way would be to write set/get functions in a language that supports
global storage (PL/Perl, PL/Tcl, PL/Python, etc.). See for example
the `set_var()` and `get_var()` functions in the `PL/Perl` documentation:

[See documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/plperl-global.html)

Comment: Thanks, but you're showing me documentation on functions, where declaring variables works. I'm in the editor or command line; whatever you would call it, and using plpgsql.